# How to solve recurrence relations in Python

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy

I am trying to write code to give numerical answers to a recurrence relation. The relation itself is simple and is defined as follows. The variable x is an integer

- p(i) = p(i+2)/2 + p(i-1)/2 if i > 0 and i < x
- p(0) = p(2)/2
- p(i)  = 1 if i >= x

This is also in this code.

```
from __future__ import division
def p(i):
    if (i == 0):
        return p(2)/2
    if (i >= x):
        return 1
    return p(i-1)/2+p(i+2)/2


x = 4
#We would like to print p(0)  for example.
```

This of course doesn't actually let you compute p(0).  How can you do this in python?

---

Is it possible to set up a system of simultaneous equations which `numpy.linalg.solve` can then solve?

Comment: Where is `x` supposed to be defined?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist It is set in the code. I set it to 4 as an example.  Clearly if x has a different value so will p(0).

Comment: I'm confused. `p(0)` is `p(2)/2`, and you have it set that way. Your code looks like it should work, though you SHOULD define `x` inside your function.

Comment: @felix What AdamSmith said is what I was getting at. Did you mean to pass it into your function?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but for me there is no answer for numbers less than x, even in normal math. p(0) is p(2)/2 but p(2) is p(1)/2 + p(3)/2 and p(1) is p(0)/2 + p(2)/2, so you can't calculate p(0), p(1) and p(2) because you should at least know the exact value of one of them.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo You have three equations and three unknowns so you should be able to work out the answer exactly.

Comment: @felix how would you do this by hand?

Comment: @AdamSmith You would write out the simultaneous equations and then try to solve them.

Comment: It's not that simple - only relation between function values is defined and not between arguments and as you probably know unlimited number of functions with unlimited number of arguments give the same results.

Comment: @felix That's not an explanation, that's just patronizing. You would solve this by writing out the program and running it, too.... I'm asking how YOU would solve it. What's the solution for `p(1)`?

Comment: @AdamSmith Let's use a,b,c,d instead of p(0),..,p(3) for ease of typing.  We know a= c/2, c = 1/2+b/2,b = a/2+d/2, d = 1/2+c/2. So we get a = 5/12, b = 2/3, c = 5/6, d = 11/12.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right this can be solved using linear algebra. What I've done below is a simple hard-coded translation. Your equations for `p(0)` to `p(3)` are coded up by rearranging them so that the right hand side is `=0`. For `p(4)` and `p(5)` which appear in the recurrence relations as base cases, there is an `=1` on the right hand side.

- `-p(0) + p(2)/2 = 0`
- `p(i-1)/2 - p(i) + p(i+2)/2 = 0` for i > 0 and i < x
- `p(i) = 1` if i >= x

Here is the program hardcoded for `n=4`

```
import numpy
a=numpy.array([[-1,   0, 0.5,  0,   0,   0], # 0
               [0.5, -1,   0,0.5,   0,   0], # 1
               [0,  0.5,  -1,  0, 0.5,   0], # 2
               [0,    0, 0.5, -1,   0, 0.5], # 3
               [0,    0,   0,  0,   1,   0], # 4
               [0,    0,   0,  0,   0,   1], # 5
              ])
b=numpy.array([0,0,0,0,1,1])
# solve ax=b
x = numpy.linalg.solve(a, b)
print x
```

*Edit*, here is the code which constructs the matrix programmatically, only tested for `n=4`!

```
n = 4

# construct a
diag = [-1]*n + [1]*2
lowdiag = [0.5]*(n-1) + [0]*2
updiag = [0.5]*n
a=numpy.diag(diag) + numpy.diag(lowdiag, -1) + numpy.diag(updiag, 2)

# solve ax=b
b=numpy.array([0]*n + [1]*2)
x = numpy.linalg.solve(a, b)

print a
print x[:n]
```

This outputs

```
[[-1.   0.   0.5  0.   0.   0. ]
 [ 0.5 -1.   0.   0.5  0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.5 -1.   0.   0.5  0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0.5 -1.   0.   0.5]
 [ 0.   0.   0.   0.   1.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1. ]]
[ 0.41666667  0.66666667  0.83333333  0.91666667]
```

which matches the solution in your comment under your question.

Comment: Thank you. Can you see how to automate this for larger values of x?

Comment: @felix I'll have a look at this: it's just building up the matrix `a` basically.

Comment: @felix general solution posted, upto you to test for `n!=4` :)

Answer (score 5):

**This is not an answer to the posted question, but this page is the top Google hit for "solve recurrence relation in Python" so I will write an answer.**

If you have a linear recurrence and you want to find the recursive formula, you can use Sympy's `find_linear_recurrence` function. For example, suppose you have the following sequence: 0, 1, 3, 10, 33, 109, 360, 1189, 3927, 12970. Then the following code produces the recurrence relation:

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import n
L = [0, 1, 3, 10, 33, 109, 360, 1189, 3927, 12970]
print(sympy.sequence(L, (n, 1, len(L))).find_linear_recurrence(len(L)))
```

The output is:

```
[3, 1]
```

So you know A(n) = 3*A(n-1) + A(n-2).

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you end up in an infinite recursion regardless of where you start, because the recursion isn't explicit, but rather ends up yielding systems of linear equations to solve. If this were a problem you had to solve using Python, I would use Python to calculate the coefficients of this system of equations and use Cramer's rule to solve it.

Edit: Specifically, your unknowns are p(0), ..., p(x-1). One coefficient row vector right off the bat is (1, 0, -1/2, 0, ..., 0) (from p(0)-p(2)/2=0), and all the others are of the form (..., -1/2, 1, 0, -1/2, ...). There are x-1 of these (one for each of p(1), ..., p(x-1)) so the system either has a unique solution or none at all. Intuitively, it seems like there should always be a unique solution.

The two last equations would be unique since they would feature p(x) and p(x+1), so those terms would be ommitted; the column vector for the RHS of Cramer's rule would then be (0, 0, ..., 0, 1/2, 1/2), I believe.

Numpy has matrix support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused because your code seems like it should do just that.

```
def p(i):
    x = 4 # your constant should be defined in-function

    if (i == 0):
        return p(2)/2
    elif (i >= x):
        return 1
    return p(i-1)/2+p(i+2)/2
```

The big problem here is your recursion. For `p(1)` it does:

```
p(0)/2                    +                    p(3)/2
p(2)/2                    +           p(2)/2 + p(4)/2
p(1)/2                    +              p(1)/2 + 1/2
# each side of the operator is now the same as the original problem!
# that's a sure sign of infinite recursion.
```

What do you EXPECT to be the output?

Comment: If you try this you will get RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: Try working through the actual logic of this recursion. For any initial value, it will end in an infinite loop.

Comment: When x= 4 the answer should be 5/6 for p(0).  Of course I would like it to work for any positive integer x.