# sympy calculate nth recurrence without using rsolve

Tags: python, sympy

I'm working on writing an application which has to solve some recurrence relations but there are some relation which can't be analytically solved by using the `rsolve` method of `sympy`. It just returns `None`. Is there a way I can force sympy to solve them numerically?

I have something like this:

```
from sympy import *

ctx = {
  "f": Function("f"),
  "x": var("x",integer=True)
}

initial_conditions = {
    0: 1,
    1: 1,
    2: 1,
    3: 1
}

f = sympify("-2*f(x-1)+11*f(x-2)+12*f(x-3)-36*f(x-4) +41**(x-4)+3 -f(x)", ctx)

# calculate f(10) here without creating a closed from
# The code below will not work rsolve returns None
solve_for = sympify("f(x)", ctx)
solved = rsolve(f, solve_for, initial_conditions)
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Do you really mean `41**`?

Comment: Yes I could also have written 41^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution to evaluate recurrence relations numerically. 
When you specify the recurrence relation as input to simplify, make sure that
the value `f(x)` is not part of the string. That is, if your recurrence relation is

```
f(x) = -2*f(x-1)+11*f(x-2)+12*f(x-3)-36*f(x-4) +41**(x-4)+3
```

your input string should be just:

```
"-2*f(x-1)+11*f(x-2)+12*f(x-3)-36*f(x-4) +41**(x-4)+3"
```

Also, this solution is limited to linear recurrence relations, though it is expandable to other cases as well.

What the code does is traverse the syntax tree of the recurrence relation and evaluate each node either by numerical computation or by looking up a known value of f(x).

```
from sympy import *
import operator
ctx = {
  "f": Function("f"),
  "x": var("x",integer=True)
}

initial_conditions = {
    0: 1,
    1: 1,
    2: 1,
    3: 1
}

func1 = sympify("-2*f(x-1)+11*f(x-2)+12*f(x-3)-36*f(x-4) +41**(x-4)+3", ctx)



def contains_function(f):
    if issubclass(type(f),Function):
        return True
    r = map(contains_function,f.args)
    return (sum(r) != 0)


def get_numeric_value(arg):

    if arg.is_number:
        if arg.is_integer:
            return int(arg)

        else:
            return float(arg)    
    else:
        return None

def evaluate_at(f, n, initial_conditions):


    if f.is_Add:
        result = 0
        op = operator.add
    elif f.is_Mul:
        result = 1
        op = operator.mul
    elif f.is_Function:
        func_arg = f.args[0]
        func_arg_val = int(func_arg.subs(func_arg.free_symbols.pop(),n))
        if not func_arg_val in initial_conditions:
            return None
        else:
            return initial_conditions[func_arg_val]

    else:
        return None

    for arg in f.args:
        if arg.is_number:
            result= op(result, get_numeric_value(arg))
        elif contains_function(arg):
            r = evaluate_at(arg,n,initial_conditions)
            if r:
                result=op(result,r)
            else:
                return None
        else:
            result =op(result,get_numeric_value(arg.subs(arg.free_symbols.pop(),n)))


    return result


known_values = dict(initial_conditions)
for n in range(4,11):
    known_values[n]  = evaluate_at(func1,n,known_values)
```

Comment: Yes I implemented something like this in the end. Just so you know you have copied the code twice! Thank you for helping!

Comment: You're welcome. I enjoyed the your question, and edited the answer to remove the dupilcate.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the case that there is not an analytic solution (see below) to this problem, I would consider going the linear algebra approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22699353/8146556):

```
from sympy import Function, rsolve
from sympy.abc import n

y = Function("y")
initial_conditions = {y(0): 1, y(1): 1, y(2): 1, y(3): 1}
f = -2*y(x-1)+11*y(x-2)+12*y(x-3)-36*y(x-4)+41**(x-4)+3-y(x)
print(rsolve(f, y(x)))
print(rsolve(f, y(x), initial_conditions))
```

Returns:

```
(-3)**x*(C0 + C1*x) + 2**x*C1*(C0 + C1*x)/C0 + 41**x/2944656 + 3/16

None
```

Comment: That makes no sense. I have enough initial conditions to be able to solve the iteratively by hand.

Comment: Would you mind including your expected output as well?

Comment: The expected output is a function where I can ask sympy give me the solution for `y(10)` or `y(11)` or `y(12)`. I don't need the closed form formula even if it would be handy.

Comment: What do you mean? There is nothing to confirm you could literally calculate it by hand bottom up. First f(4) then f(5) and so on. The recurrence only goes back 4 maximum so if you have the last 4 you can always calculate the next one. And since you have the 4 initial conditions this is perfectly valid and you can calculate it to any number >= 4

Comment: So you also get `f(4)` gives `y(4)=-11`?

Comment: To solve it numerically, you might have some better luck with this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22699353/8146556